# How can I get the Python compiler string programmatically?

Tags: python

The Python Interpreter Entry Message contains a string that describes the compiler.

For example on my machine, the Entry Message says:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Where `[MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]` is the compiler string.

How can i get this string programmatically?

Comment: You should look into the `re` module, which is the built in python regular expression module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get information like this from the [platform](https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html) module, for example:

```
import platform
platform.python_compiler()
```

gives me:

```
'GCC 4.9.2'
```